# Guaranteeing Unique Field Combinations

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am trying to implement a table that groups rows in another table into lists.  So I have defined my table as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LINKAGE",
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "PARENTPO", "MEMBERPO"})
    })
public class Linkage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long        id;

    private UserRec parentPo;

    private UserRec memberPo;
```

I want to make sure that each row in the table has a unique combination of (parentPo and memberPo) but for some reason my **uniqueConstraints** term isn't working.  My buggy early-draft code ends up creating redundant records when I should get an EntityExistsException.  Have I coded this correctly?

This is using EclipseLink 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd in front of Derby.

Comment: You are using column names "PARENTPO", "MEMBERPO" for the constraints, but you haven't specified which column names are to be used in the parentPo and memberPo mappings.  Are you sure it is using PARENTPO and not something like PARENTPO_ID by default?  Try specifying the foreign key in your mapping with a joincolumn annotation, verify that JPA is creating your schema and show what it is creating

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.   Yes the UserRec has an id field of its own that would be used for comparison -- I thought JPA would infer the comparison from the primary key.   I will see if this fixes it.

Comment: @Chris it turns out your suggestion is the right one.   If you want to post your reply as an answer I will mark it for you.